# Is there a specific term for such collections of filters?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, filters

Let $U$ be a set.

Concept = "a set $\mathscr{C}$ of proper filters on $U$ such that if $X\in\mathscr{C}$ and $Y$ is a proper filter on $U$ and $Y\supseteq X$, then $Y\in\mathscr{C}$."

Is there a specific term or a combination of terms to succinctly describe this concept?

If there are no existing term, please help me to devise a good English word to describe this situation (in the book I am writing).

Comment: Upward closed set of filters.